# Does anybody know how to add 1 to the naming of these nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following example below creates a dictionary named special from a list named example, those dictionary values are nested in a form similar to

```
{'name0' :
 {'name' : 'Harry James Potter',
 'phone' : 'n/a',
 'address' : '4 Pivet Drive Little Whinging, Surrey'}}
```

and next would be for an example

```
 {'name1' :
 {'name' : 'Sirius Black',
 'phone' : 'n/a',
 'address' : '12 Grimald Place London'}}
```

what I am wondering and not able to accomplish is how to change the last line of code below to name the nested dictionaries beginning from 'name1' and so on and so forth...

```
example=[]
with open(sys.argv[1], encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        return_from_add_2.append(row)
special = {f'name{i}':v for i, v in enumerate(example)}
```

I've tried to add an i=1 to the last line inside of and right before it but i get a syntax error.

Comment: every time you find yourself using serially named variables or keys like name1, name2, it's a good indication that you need a different data structure - in this case, a list, not a dict.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The reason I am using a dictionary is so that each value has a title adhering to it which i can use to append the rows to a csv file that already has column headers, to make matching data for the headers. If i did this with a list it would get rather complex although you do make a valid point. Earlier on in the process i was frusturated enough with the naming conventions of name1, name2 and so forth, however i couldn't get rid of them when i learned when doing a replace key that naming them all 'person' wasn't doable -case of them no longer being unique dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Option 1: tell enumerate to start with 1

```
special = {f'name{i}':v for i, v in enumerate(example, 1)}
```

Option 2: increment i by 1 inside the f-string

```
special = {f'name{i+1}':v for i, v in enumerate(example)}
```

Example:

```
example = [("v1", "v2"), ("v3", "v4")]
special1 = {f'name{i}':v for i, v in enumerate(example, 1)}
special2 = {f'name{i+1}':v for i, v in enumerate(example)}
```

Output:

```
{'name1': ('v1', 'v2'), 'name2': ('v3', 'v4')}
{'name1': ('v1', 'v2'), 'name2': ('v3', 'v4')}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner data structure is a nested dictionary and it seems they key name is unique for each entry you want to reference. Below are a couple of methods to access the data.

You can dynamically generate the key and use that to access the value.

```
list_of_nested_dictionaries = [{'name0' : {'name' : 'Harry James Potter', 'phone' : 'n/a', 'address' : '4 Pivet Drive Little Whinging, Surrey'}},{'name1' : {'name' : 'Sirius Black', 'phone' : 'n/a', 'address' : '12 Grimald Place London'}}]
i = 0
for nested_dictionary in list_of_nested_dictionaries:
    dynamic_key = f'name{i}'
    character_name = nested_dictionary.get(dynamic_key).get('name')
    print(f'{character_name}')
    i+=1
```

You can use the dictionary in-built functions to access the data

```
list_of_nested_dictionaries = [{'name0' : {'name' : 'Harry James Potter', 'phone' : 'n/a', 'address' : '4 Pivet Drive Little Whinging, Surrey'}},{'name1' : {'name' : 'Sirius Black', 'phone' : 'n/a', 'address' : '12 Grimald Place London'}}]
for nested_dictionary in list_of_nested_dictionaries:
    for key in nested_dictionary.keys():
        character_name = nested_dictionary.get(key).get('name')
        print(f'{character_name}')
```